# List of images with checkbox (user registration)

Tags: 7, users, entities, media

This is what I would like to do:

When a user registers on the website they have to give in if some options like for example if they are politically engaged, professionally engaged, an expert, ... .

I also want a field that contains 3 images. And based on the chosen options of the user I would like to select 1,2 or 3 of them. So the user can contain image 1 & 2 or ... .

So I was thinking of 3 images with 3 checkboxes and cross the checkboxes next to the images (programmatically). But is this a good way to do this? And if yes, how can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by the following.

Go to Configuration » People » Account settings

Add a **Field type :** *List (text)* and **WIDGET:** *Check boxes/radio buttons*

In ***Allowed values list***  textarea add `key|<img src ='/your/path/to/image' />`

Enter one `<img>` per line and set *Number of values* as Unlimited (to appear as checkboxes)

That's it. I tested it and working fine.

Add `key` whatever you want.You may have to make minor CSS changes in order to align checkbox and image.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @nielsv Glad to hear that. :)